# Can node.js worker threads run on all CPUs and all cores?

Tags: node.js, multicore, worker

I understand that node.js can run on multiple cores on at least one CPU. What's not clear to me is whether it can run on more than one CPU. For example, if I have a 4-CPU machine with 10 cores in each CPU, can a single node.js process take advantage of all 40 cores, or just 10? Does it depend on the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Other than performance effects (such as NUMA), multi-socket systems work exactly like single-socket-multi-core systems, whatever that implies for node.js.  They're all SMP systems with multiple CPU cores and cache-coherent shared memory.

OSes will run threads across all physical cores in the system, so all that matters is that your workload is threaded at all.

The only thing that would be different is a cluster of machines with shared memory that's not cache-coherent; in that case you wouldn't be running a single instance of an OS across all the cores.